# Integrating Collapse functionality of Bootstrap with Django Backend. How to use for loops?

Tags: html, django, for-loop, bootstrap-4

I'm struggling with a task in Django.
I have my database up and running with information on resellers. (name, address, region etc...)
and I want to implement Bootstrap collapse functionality where each card is a region.  I was able to do that hardcoding the handling of the region. So in my base.html file I have:

```
  <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
              <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                  Region1
                </button>
              </h2>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
              <div class="card-body">
                {% block content_Region1 %}
                {% endblock %}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

and  in the block content of Region1 I use the home.html template as follow:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content_Veneto %}
<div class = "container">
        {% for reseller in resellers %}
          {% if reseller.region == "Veneto" %}
            <div class="reseller_name">
              <a href="{% url 'reseller_detail' reseller.id %}">
                <p>{{reseller.name}} - {{reseller.cityname}}</p>
              </a>
            </div>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```

What I would like to have is a list containing all the regions that are present in by database and then, in the base.html file I would like to do something like:

```
{% for region in list_regions %}
<div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
              <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                  region
                </button>
              </h2>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
              <div class="card-body">
                {% block content_region %}
                {% endblock %}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
{% endfor %}
```

so that I do not have to write the same code multiple times. Any idea?
The issue is that I'm not sure how to get the region_list out of the database.

Thanks and sorry for the long post!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of blocks use the [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include) template tag:

```
{% for region in list_regions %}
<div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
              <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                  region
                </button>
              </h2>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
              <div class="card-body">
                {% include "template_name.html" %}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Change `template_name.html` with your template which you want to include.

Comment: ehi @abdulazikbarkat thanks for you answer! I edited my question because it was not clear my problem ( which is how to extract the list of regions from my database and then what you mentioned. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @gigibotte you should add your model for that (also perhaps view) anyway something like `ModelNameForRegion.objects.all()` should get you all regions. (Replace `ModelNameForRegion` with the actual model name)

Comment: ehi @abdulazikbarkat thanks again :) so my  is currently called Reseller and has the various elements (address, name region etc...)  should I create a new model that create the list of regions how you suggested?

Comment: @gigibotte You can pass a list if you have one to the template. If it is something you will get from users etc. you should add a Model for it as you likely need to store it in the database.